# chem-biochem options not working

Tags: biblatex

I would like to use the chem-biochem style for biblatex but have the citation numbers in the text and the bibliography in square brackets. There is the option biblabel=brackets which I understand from the documentation should do this, but it actually doesn't change anything.

Here is my MWE:

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-biochem, biblabel=brackets]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{jobnames.bib}

\begin{document}

Blablabla \cite{Labov1972,Chomsky1957}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Whereas the bib file contains:

```
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
```

Could anyone get this option working?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`chem-biochem.cbx` redefines square brackets to always be round brackets. This disables `\mkbibbrackets` which is used with `biblabel=brackets`. To get square brackets back use

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibleftbracket}{\blx@postpunct[}
\renewcommand*{\bibrightbracket}{\blx@postpunct]\midsentence}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I guess I can fix that ...

Comment: Is there also a way to change the numbers to be non-italic again?

Comment: @E.Thienhaus `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{#1}`.

Comment: Awesome! The last thing I'm trying to do now it to get control over the indentation of the first line of an entry. I already tried to modify \parindent, but it seems to have no effect on the chem-biochem style...

Comment: @E.Thienhaus What do you want to do? I think this would warrant a new question.

Comment: @E.Thienhaus If this answer answered your question please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓)

Answer (score 3):

The `biblatex` package splits *bibliography* and `citation` style. Here, you only want the *Biochemistry* bibliography style

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=chem-biochem,citestyle=numeric,biblabel=brackets]{biblatex}
```