# biblatex chem-biochem bibliography indent

Tags: biblatex

after I got very helpful advice to some modifications of the chem-biochem biblatex style in another, question, I have one more thing I'd like to alter:

By default chem-biochem creates a small indent in the first line of an entry in the bibliography. I'd like to get rid of that, if somehow possible and have all right aligned as in most other styles.

Thank you!
[image: Example]

Comment: You can make your question *much* easier if you provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). That way people don't have to go back through all your questions or build something themselves.

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex-chem`'s `chem-biochem` still uses some pre-3.3 code. See [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864). In particular you need to replace `\ifblank` with `\ifdefvoid`.

```
\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}
       {\mkbibnameprefix{#3\isdot}%
        \ifprefchar{}{\addhighpenspace}}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}
       {\addcomma\addlowpenspace
        \mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}
       {\addlowpenspace
        \mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\addcomma}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}
       {\addlowpenspace
        \mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}
       {\addlowpenspace
        \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}
       {\addlowpenspace
        \mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}%
}
```

The definition in `chem-biochem.bbx` using the old macros does not quite work with the new name format and causes a spurious space in certain situations. That's what you are seeing as an incorrect indentation.

With the fix your MWE from [chem-biochem options not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/411737/35864) becomes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=chem-biochem, biblabel=brackets]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibleftbracket}{\blx@postpunct[}
\renewcommand*{\bibrightbracket}{\blx@postpunct]\midsentence}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}
       {\mkbibnameprefix{#3\isdot}%
        \ifprefchar{}{\addhighpenspace}}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}
       {\addcomma\addlowpenspace
        \mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}
       {\addlowpenspace
        \mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\addcomma}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}
       {\addlowpenspace
        \mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}
       {\addlowpenspace
        \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}
       {\addlowpenspace
        \mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}%
} 

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll update this shortly ...

Comment: thank you a lot! It works very well on my end and It's definetely something I would never be able to come up with...